# Is there any way to join ngForm and ngModel from different components?

Tags: angular

I have 2 level component hierarchy. In parent I have form tag and in children component I have inputs. I need to validate form on top level based in inputs from children components. Here I tried to replicate it       **plnkr.co/Hx9MzYyJaF9swa7PfY8T** (sorry can't insert link here because of strange error from stakeoverflow)

Comment: The child component should implement https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/ControlValueAccessor-interface.html to be able to act as form control

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will try it. Maybe you can post your comment as an answer? I believe it is right solution.